# Get [NSIndexPath] array for rows in section of UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got a section of rows in a tableView (section 1) and I need to initialize an `[NSIndexPath]` array for all rows in that section.

I know I can count the number of rows in the section easily enough:

```
let rowsInSection = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1)
```

But that only gets me the row count, not the index paths.

What's the cleanest, most "Swift-like" way of retrieving the index paths?

An example of what I'm looking for:

```
func indexPathsForRowsInSection(section: Int) -> [NSIndexPath] {
    // magic happens here
    return indexPathsForRowsInSection
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop to populate the array.

Comment: you can use `for` to loop the count of row, then declare indexPath directly like `let index = NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)`. i will be your item row

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this in Swift 3:

```
func indexPathsForRowsInSection(_ section: Int, numberOfRows: Int) -> [NSIndexPath] {
    return (0..<numberOfRows).map{NSIndexPath(row: $0, section: section)}
}
```

Comment: Great, nice solution!

Comment: Updated for Swift 3

Comment: @brandonscript Note my modification of your update: I'd remove the `section` label from the first parameter so as not have to call this by saying `...Section(section...`.

Comment: Ah yes absolutely.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you want this, but you could do as follow:

```
let paths = (0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(section)).map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: section) }
return paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise Swift 3 extension for UITableView based on Vincent and Matt's answers:

```
extension UITableView {
    func indexPathsForRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> [NSIndexPath] {
        return (0..<self.numberOfRows(inSection: section)).map { NSIndexPath(row: $0, section: section) }
    }
}

// usage
tableView.indexPathsForRowsInSection(aNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let section = 1
 let numberOfRows = 15

 let indexPaths = (0..<numberOfRows).map { i in return 
                                          IndexPath(item:i, section: section)  
                                         }
```